# How do I add divs to a sitemap?

Tags: navigation

I have the [Sitemap](http://drupal.org/project/site_map) module installed and it creates an unordered list of my chosen menu's items.

Main Menu looks like this:

Home
 - submenuitem1
 - submenuitem2
 - submenuitemn

Services
 - submenuitem1
 - submenuitem2
 - submenuitemn

References
 - submenuitem1
 - submenuitem2
 - submenuitemn

Links
 - submenuitem1
 - submenuitem2
 - submenuitemn

How can I add DIVs to each main menu item with its subitems ( Home+subemenuitems, Service+submenuitems etc.) ?

I managed to override site_map_menu_link to give it some depth at least.

```
function MYTHEME_site_map_menu_link(array $variables) {
    $element = $variables['element'];
    $sub_menu = '';

    $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'menu-' . $element['#original_link']['plid'];
    $menu_id = 'menu-' . $element['#original_link']['plid'];
    $link_depth = 'depth-'. $element['#original_link']['depth'];

    if ($element['#below']) {
      $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
    }

    $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
    return '<div class="'.$menu_id." ".$link_depth.'"><li>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `theme_site_map_box` in your `template.php`!

I've done something similar before where I've changed the H2's to H3's:

Try something like the following in your `template.php`

```
function MYTHEME_site_map_box($variables) {
  $title = $variables['title'];
  $content = $variables['content'];
  $attributes = $variables['attributes'];

  $output = '';
  if (!empty($title) || !empty($content)) {
    $output .= '<div' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . '>';
    if (!empty($title)) {
      $output .= '<h3 class="title">' . $title . '</h3>';
    }
    if (!empty($content)) {
      $output .= '<div class="content"><div class="MYCLASS">' . $content . '</div></div>';
    }
    $output .= '</div>';
  }

  return $output;
}
```

I can't remember off the top of my head the structure of `$content`, but the above code should put an extra div around each section of the site map with the class of `MYCLASS`.

API Docs: [`theme_site_map_box()`](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/theme_site_map_box/7)

Comment: Unfortunaly the code only put an extra div in between content div and the ul of the whole main menu, but not for each section of the main menu.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use [menu_block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block) module to create blocks for each list. Then you can target them individually, mix in other content etc.

> It provides configurable blocks of menu trees starting with any level
>   of any menu. And more!

Kim

Comment: Hi Kim, menu_block is not an option for me, because we have an installation with the domain access module and lots of domains. with lots of menu blocks the administration gets real confusing. so we need a clean coded solution.